# Installing py27-scipy not working for py27-cairo using macports

Tags: scipy, macports, cairo

```
(graphite)[nai:~]$ sudo port install py27-cairo
--->  Computing dependencies for py27-cairo
--->  Cleaning py27-cairo
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors: 100.0%
--->  Found 5 broken file(s), matching files to ports
--->  Found 3 broken port(s), determining rebuild order
--->  Rebuilding in order
     py27-scipy @0.10.1 +gcc45
     qemu @1.4.0 +target_i386+target_x86_64
     qt4-mac @4.8.3 +quartz
--->  Computing dependencies for py27-scipy
--->  Fetching archive for py27-scipy
--->  Attempting to fetch py27-scipy-0.12.0_2+gcc45.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2 from http://jog.id.packages.macports.org/macports/packages/py27-scipy
--->  Attempting to fetch py27-scipy-0.12.0_2+gcc45.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2 from http://mse.uk.packages.macports.org/sites/packages.macports.org/py27-scipy
--->  Attempting to fetch py27-scipy-0.12.0_2+gcc45.darwin_11.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/py27-scipy
--->  Fetching distfiles for py27-scipy
--->  Attempting to fetch scipy-0.12.0.tar.gz from http://jog.id.distfiles.macports.org/macports/mpdistfiles/py-scipy/0.12.0_1
--->  Verifying checksum(s) for py27-scipy
--->  Extracting py27-scipy
--->  Applying patches to py27-scipy
--->  Configuring py27-scipy
--->  Building py27-scipy
^[[BError: org.macports.build for port py27-scipy returned: command execution failed
Please see the log file for port py27-scipy for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_python_py-scipy/py27-scipy/main.log
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
Error rebuilding py27-scipy
    while executing
"error "Error rebuilding $portname""
    (procedure "revupgrade_scanandrebuild" line 382)
    invoked from within
"revupgrade_scanandrebuild broken_port_counts $opts"
    (procedure "macports::revupgrade" line 5)
    invoked from within
"macports::revupgrade $opts"
    (procedure "action_revupgrade" line 2)
    invoked from within
"action_revupgrade $action $portlist $opts"
    (procedure "action_target" line 94)
    invoked from within
"$action_proc $action $portlist [array get global_options]"
    (procedure "process_cmd" line 95)
    invoked from within
"process_cmd $remaining_args"
    invoked from within
"if { [llength $remaining_args] > 0 } {

    # If there are remaining arguments, process those as a command
    set exit_status [process_cmd $remaining..."
    (file "/opt/local/bin/port" line 4785)
```

So I have py27-scipy installed

```
(graphite)[nai:~]$ port installed py27-scipy
The following ports are currently installed:
  py27-scipy @0.10.1_3+gcc45 (active)
```

Comment: ThisThis is tool localized - a one off question appears to be off-topic because it is about 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running

```
[nai:~]$ sudo port clean py27-numpy py27-scipy py27-matplotlib py27-ipython +notebook py27-pandas py27-sympy py27-nose
```

followed by a

```
[nai:~]$ sudo port install py27-numpy py27-scipy py27-matplotlib py27-ipython +notebook py27-pandas py27-sympy py27-nose
```

I ran `port self update` and it probably broke some stuff.